# How do I receive the letter from the Jarl's Steward in Hearthfire?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I just bought the Hearthfire DLC and as soon as I travel somewhere, a courier approaches me and says he has 2 letters for me. One from the orphanage and one from the Jarl's steward.
The problem is that I only receive the first letter.

This is what my inventory looks like after speaking to the courier.
In case you can't read the book's titles on the screenshot, they are *Breezehome Furnishings*, *Consider Adoption* and *Gallus's encoded journal*.
[image]

As you can see I removed all my letters and notes that are not quest items before speaking to him.

Is this a bug or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug. Luckily, it is a bug with 0 consequences - the letter is only to inform you of the land being available, you can still go to the jarl/steward and talk to them about the land without getting the letter. Land is available in Falkreath, Morthal and Dawnstar.

Comment: But where should I go? The courier doesn't metion any city.

Comment: I've added the list of cities that have land for sale to the answer.